# How do I add a extra zero to my output while still having it alinged with my table?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
   cout << setw(16) << "$" << setw(9) << fixed << showpoint 
               << setprecision(2) << Charge << setw(10) << KWHused 
               << setw(10) << setfill('0') << meter_after << setw(10) << setfill('0') << meter_before
               << setw(21) << Cust_Name;
```

Output:

```
               ===================
               UTILITY BILLING LOG
               SPRING 2017
               ===================



                                       METER READINGS
                  CHARGE   KWH USED   CURRENT  PREVIOUS  CUSTOMER NAME
               ==========  ========  ========  ========  ===================
               $   163.00       70000043051500004304450000000 Edward L Jones
000000000000000$000240.75000000115000012365810001235431000000 Meryl Petersen
```

Input :

```
                         04304450  04305150 Edward L Jones
                         01235431  01236581 Meryl Petersen
                         00033333  00032223 Absent Dweller
```

Supposed Output:

```
                  ===================
                  UTILITY BILLING LOG
                  SPRING 2017
                  ===================


                                       METER READINGS                
                  CHARGE   KWH USED   CURRENT  PREVIOUS  CUSTOMER NAME
               ==========  ========  ========  ========  =================== 
               $   163.00       700  04305150  04304450  Edward L Jones
               $   260.30      1150  01236581  01235431  Meryl Peterson
```

Link of how it should look:

http://www.cis.famu.edu/~cop3014cjoe/Homeworks/spring2017_PROG8_UtilityBilling

Answer (score 2):

Field lengths are wrong, you just need to add the needed spacings and reset the filling char:

```
cout << setfill(' ')
     << setw(16) << "$" << setw(9) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << Charge
     << "  "
     << setw(8) << KWHused 
     << "  "
     << setw(8) << setfill('0') << meter_after
     << "  "
     << setw(8) << setfill('0') << meter_before
     << "  "
     << setw(21) << Cust_Name
     << endl;
```

Comment: This is what it looks like now:   



000000000000000        $000240.75    00001150  01236581  01235431  000000 Meryl Petersen